# can't listen to tips on bill Jelen podcast disc

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, podcasts

Am using Windows 7-64 bit--have the bill Jelen disc with his podcasts on it.  Can open the disc, select the podcast I want to listen to -it shows up on my screen but there seems to be no place to click to have the podcast actually start running.

Have used this disc before with Windows XP and Windows-not 64- and had no problem- would just click on the podcast and it would start to play.  Would try on my other computer that it worked on but that computer is dead.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like on your x64 computer, the filetype on the disk is not associated to a audio player.  If you double click on the podcast file, does Windows offer to find an application to open the file with it?